while installing Kubernetes package related error occur, image attached how i can solve it ? (all ports are open)

Here's an inline link to install kubernetes
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

Please install CRI - crio which will install dependent packages.  Please refer k8s documentation which has details of installing crio.
